# Counting # of rows in table which contain file_name

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a page which displays products added to a database.

I need to use 'foreach' to automatically display all products.

Im stuck with one part where I need to display the number of downloads of each product. The only way to do this is to count the number of rows which contain the file name of the product in the downloads table.

This is what I use so far, but its not working:

```
SELECT * FROM products, file_product, files, downloads WHERE products.id = file_product.product_id AND file_product.file_id = files.id AND files.file_name = downloads.file_name
```

These are my tables: [products, file_product, files, downloads]

[image: Table: products]

[image: Table: file_product]

[image: Table: files]

[image: Table: downloads]

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you're doing this the hard way.  I might suggest you look at mysql's grouping functions, specifically `GROUP BY`.  You won't have to loop over the query at all, just the results.

Something like

```
SELECT `file_name`, COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `files` GROUP BY `file_name`;
```

The results should look something like this:

```
---------------------------
| file_name        | count|
--------------------------|
| background-2.png |  2   |
| foo.png          |  1   |
---------------------------
```

You can `JOIN` that with your `file_product` table if you need to limit it to only files for the current product, as what I wrote will give you all files for all products.

Example:

```
SELECT
    f.`file_name`,
    COUNT(*) AS `count`
FROM `files` f
JOIN `file_product` fp
    ON fp.`file_id` = f.`id`
JOIN `product` p
    ON fp.`product_id` = ?
JOIN `downloads` d
    ON d.`file_name` = f.`file_name`
GROUP BY `file_name`;
```

`?` is where you put the product id for the current product.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! How do I implement this in PHP so that I can simply 'echo' the number count for each product?

Comment: @rohanmcdermott: That's not a simple answer.  I don't know how you've opened your database connection and are querying.  If you're using a framework you'll need to use the framework's conventions.  If you're using straight PHP then you must have opened a database connection using PDO or mysqli.  Take a look at the "Examples" section on this page: http://us1.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php.  Example #2 is the simpler way that lets you use the query as I've written it, with the question mark.  PHP will replace it with the value you pass in the execute method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write :

```
SELECT `file_name'`, COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM table GROUP BY `count` ORDER BY `count` DESC;
```

Then, this command returns how many rows per table for each file_name group by descroissant order.

In order to implement whith PHP :

```
<?php
// connect to MySQL
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'login', 'password');

// select database
mysql_select_db('database_name',$db);

// SQL query
$sql = 'SELECT `file_name`, COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM table GROUP BY `count` ORDER BY `count` DESC;';


$req = mysql_query($sql) or die('Error SQL !<br>'.$sql.'<br>'.mysql_error());

// close mysql
mysql_close();
?>
```

I can't test it, so it's maybe false :/

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! How do I implement this in PHP so that I can simply 'echo' the number count for each product?

Comment: @rohanmcdermott, It's sounding an awful lot like you want somebody to write this for you.  This is against the spirit of Stack Overflow.  You've received answers as to what your query should look like.

Comment: @Crashspeeder We help people and sometimes we don't get a feedback ^^ Hopfully rohanmcdermott understands the SO philosophy ;)